# How do I set the axes to a certain value? I have tried using set_xlim and set_ylim but Matplotlib does not recognise them

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm writing a `matplotlib` program to plot a simple graph of sunspot numbers against the year that they were recorded. I want to set my `y` axis to begin at 0 and my `x` axis to begin at 1725. I have tried using `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` but I get the error message `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_ylim'`

I am a matplotlib beginner. I previously tried using `plt.xticks(np.arange())` to try and change the axes but this didn't do anything outside of just changing the frequency of ticks.

```
plt.set_xlim(xmin=1750) # set x axis minimum to 1750 (the time axis)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1750,2050,25)) # ticks begin at 1750, every 25 years
plt.set_ylim(ymin=0) # set y axis minimum to 0
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,max(numbers)+100,50)) # ticks begin at 0, every 50 sunspots
```

I want my axes to begin at 0 and 1750. Instead when I plot my graph I get a buffer around 1750 and 0 which looks sloppy and an error message for using `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`.

Comment: It's `ax.set_xlim` or `plt.xlim`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I do `plt.xlim(xmax=1750)` my graph compresses itself into the right half of the plot but using `plt.ylim` causes no issues. Do you know why this is?

Comment: I know nothing about "your graph", so I can't know the problem. See [mcve].